# AutoResize DataGridView Columns on TabPages

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, autosize, tabpage

I'm having a little bit problem with AutoResize on DataGridView.
Im doing it this way :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
 {
      tabControl_Rozliczenie.TabPages.Add("Page " + list[i]);
      var dataGridView = new DataGridView()
      {
           Name = "dataGridView_" + list[i],
           Dock = DockStyle.Fill
      };

      dataGridView.CellValueChanged += 
              new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView_ety_CellValueChanged);
      dataGridView.CellFormatting += 
              new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dataGridView_ety_CellFormatting);
      dataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;

      tabControl_Rozl.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(dataGridView);
      dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells); 
      dgwList.Add(dataGridView);
 }
```

It's adding new TabPages and DataGridViews on them but this part :

```
 dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells)
```

AutoResize only DataGridView on tabPage[0] = first page, on the rest of them it doesn't work.

Can some one help me with finding code problem?

Assumption is :

It has to AutoResize DataGridView on each TabControlPage.

Comment: Make sure the TabPage is selected i.e. visible before trying to auto-resize its columns! Unselected TabPages are preventing any layout of its children..

Comment: Of course I forget about it. It works now, thanks a lot ! Unfortunately I cannot accept this as an answer cause it's comment.

Comment: I wrote it out as an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TabControl` has a nasty habit of preventing the children of **unselected** `TabPages` from doing their layout.

So you'll need to **select** each `TabPage` before filling the `DataGridView` and setting its `AutoResizeColumns` property:

```
tabControl_Rozliczenie.TabPages.Add("Page " + list[i]);
tabControl_Rozliczenie.SelectedTab = tabControl_Rozliczenie.TabPages["Page " + list[i]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, so apologies if it doesn't help, but could the issue be that you are adding the dataGridView to the controls list and *then* changing the AutoResizeColumns option? Have you tried changing the order to:

```
dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
tabControl_Rozl.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(dataGridView);
```

?